# In an irreversible or reversible isobaric process, is $Q$ equal to $dH$? is $dH$ equal to $W$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, reversibility, gas

First of all,

Is an irreversible isobaric process even considered a truly isobaric process? Or can it be neglected when considering generalized rules for isobaric processes?

Heat added or removed to an isobaric process can't all go towards the change in enthalpy right? Part of it must go towards the work.. Or am I wrong here?

If I am right, why do most books state that Q=dH in an isobaric process?

Also, work done on the system should be less than than the heat removed from the system right?

EDIT:

So, when looking at Greiner Neise thermodynamics and statistical mechanics, the general equation is reported as:

$\ dH|_p = \delta Q|_p + \delta W^{rev}_{other}|_p$

Where the $\ W^{rev}_{other}$ is utilizable work, not simply volume work against the constant external pressure.

Comment: Suppose that you have a gas at pressure p in equilibrium with the surroundings, also at pressure p, through a massless frictionless piston. If you suddenly change the surroundings pressure to P and hold it at that constant value until the system re-equilibrates at P, would you consider this irreversible process isobaric. Or, does the surroundings pressure have to be held at p throughout the process for the process to be considered (by you) isobaric?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/404425) to format equations and variables.

Comment: @ChetMiller Would you mind looking at the equation I edited in?

Answer (score 2):

Enthalpy is state function so it doesn't depend on the path: it only depends on the initial state and final state.  If your system can only do pressure-volume work:
$$\begin{align}
\Delta H &= (U_f + P_fV_f) - (U_i + P_iV_i) \\
&= \Delta U + P \Delta V \\
&= dQ_p+dW_p + P\Delta V \\
&= dQ_p - P\Delta V + P\Delta V \\
&= dQ_p
\end{align}$$
So the enthalpy change of the system is equivalent to how much heat the system absorbs.  This is why the enthalpy is a "natural choice" when you're considering a constant-pressure process.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/404425) to format equations and variables.

Comment: Would you mind looking at the equation I edited in and telling me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of non-PV work $$ H = U + PV \Rightarrow dH = dU + PdV + VdP = TdS + VdP$$
where by the definition of entropy $$ dS = \frac{\delta Q}{T} \Longrightarrow dH = \delta Q + VdP$$
so in an isobaric process $$dP = 0 \Longrightarrow \boxed{dH = \delta Q}$$
*regardless* of overall reversibility / irreversibility $(\Delta S_{univ} > 0)$